# How to search iOS Address book efficiently

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abaddressbook

My app has the ability of sharing its content between different instances of the app i.e. there is a button that lets me attach a document to an email and send it off to another user of the app.  When they receive this file it opens up in their instance of the app.  This is all working.

However, during the import of this data file, I need the app to add address book records to the address book unless the email address is already in the address book then it must just return the ABRecordRef.

I need to decide which approach is more efficient:

A - Loop through the entire address book creating an array of user defined objects with name and email address (which is all I require) and ABRecordRef.  Then when the app is reading the attachment file XML it must check this NSArray each time.

B - Access the address book every time I encounter a contact in the attachment XML and search for it based on email address e.g. ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople

Any other ideas?

Comment: So you mean for e.g. use an NSDictionary and have the email address as the key?

Comment: Why not just test it yourself?  Theoretical answers to this type of question tend to be lacking because they can't take into account all the unknowns.

Comment: I hear you, however it will save time though if someone has experience with this though.  It is also difficult to test as who knows how big some people's address books are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: this applies to searching by e-mail address.  If you are searching by name this does not apply.

For an arbitrarily sized address book with a fixed size number of addresses to lookup, searching the address book will be faster.  This is because the initial cost of putting all the addresses into a hash is guaranteed to take at least linear (`O(n)`) time with respect to the number of addresses in the book while (assuming the address book is at least moderately efficien) lookup should be either logarithmic (`O(ln(n)`) or constant time (`O(x)`) depending on the implementation since you have a fixed number of addresses to check.

Edit:
A brief survey of the address book api shows that you can't simply "search the address book", you have to make a copy and then filter it.

> Using Record Identifiers
>
> Every record in the Address Book database has a unique record identifier. This identifier always refers to the same record, unless that record is deleted or the MobileMe sync data is reset. Record identifiers can be safely passed between threads. They are not guaranteed to remain the same across devices.
>
> The recommended way to keep a long-term reference to a particular record is to store the first and last name, or a hash of the first and last name, in addition to the identifier. When you look up a record by ID, compare the record’s name to your stored name. If they don’t match, use the stored name to find the record, and store the new ID for the record.
>
> To get the record identifier of a record, use the function ABRecordGetRecordID. To find a person record by identifier, use the function ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID. To find a group by identifier, use the function ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID. To find a person record by name, use the function ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName.

Comment: [ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName) looks like it can search without first making a copy.

Comment: That is true, except that he isn't searching by name, he's searching by e-mail address and there isn't a way to retrieve people by e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

Given the limitations of the address book in iOS, copying the address book into a NSDictionary is going to be faster than trying to search each time.

Assuming you are fine with overwriting on email address collisions, I would create a dictionary with the email address as the key and the ABRecordRef stored as a NSNumber for the object.

I would do all this on a background queue and then monitor for address book changes and reload the dictionary as needed.

We've encountered users with several thousand entries in their address books.  In those cases, you may want to create a record object and store it in Core Data.  By filtering on the last modified date, you can determine whether or not to update the email addresses for a given record.